# Fix for Xcode Tile Editor Bug?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

[image]

I'm testing the title editor that comes with Xcode 8 (8.2.1).  It seems that there's a major bug.  I can create a tile map.  But if I set the title size to 32 x 32 and then quit Xcode and reopen the same project, Xcode resets the size to 128 x 128.  According to [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71917), it's a known bug.  Does anybody know a fix?  If Xcode redefines the tile size every time I open a tile map, it's kind of useless.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What size are the tiles in `Background.sks`?

Comment: The tiles are all in 32 x 32.